# How to combine two or more rows in jQuery DataTables using a column value?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTable where I have multiple rows with some repeated column values. So I have to combine all those rows to a single one by add all other columns together.

Eg:

```
Item             Total      Sold      Reserved
Item1(SourceX)      10         5          5
Item2(SourceZ)       8         3          5
Item1(SourceY)       15        10         5
```

I expect a result of

```
Item             Total      Sold      Reserved
Item1(Combined)      25         15        10
Item2(SourceZ)       8         3          5
```

Comment: On what basis you are combining? also, you should  combine this on server not in juqery/datatables

Comment: Item name, like 'Item1'. There are two rows named 'Item1'. Yes we can combine in server. Actually I don't want to touch the server side code because I am collecting the data from an endpoint. If there is no way I will combine in server

Comment: Combined in server. But still if there is a way in front-end, I would like to know

Comment: Show us the code, some sample data, a description of the desired output - and perhaps someone is able to help :)